# Unable to read file inside Docker image using std::fs methods

Tags: file, docker, rust

I have a simple Rust application which reads JSON files like below:

```
fn main() {
    let config_dir = std::path::PathBuf::from("config/endpoints.json");
    println!(">>>>>>> Canonicalized path {:?}", std::fs::canonicalize(&config_dir));

    println!(">>>>>>>>read endpoint file");
    println!("Does file exist? {}", std::path::Path::new("config/endpoints.json").exists());
}
```

The application, when run with `cargo run` returns the correct file path, but when I add the files inside a Docker image similar to [the rust-musl-builder](https://github.com/emk/rust-musl-builder/blob/master/examples/using-diesel/Dockerfile), I get errors:

> Canonicalized pathErr(Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" })
>
> Does path exist false

My `Dockerfile` looks like this

```
FROM ekidd/rust-musl-builder AS builder

# Add our source code.
ADD . ./

RUN sudo chown -R rust:rust /home/rust

RUN cargo build --release

FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates

EXPOSE 3001

COPY --from=builder \
    /home/rust/src/config/ \
    /usr/local/bin/config/

COPY --from=builder \
    /home/rust/src/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/app \
    /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/app

ENV RUST_BACKTRACE=1

CMD /usr/local/bin/app
```

How can I read a file inside a Docker image?

Comment: @shepmaster Thanks for the comments. I edited and added the details

Comment: When I attempt to run this, I get `COPY failed: stat /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/79...5/home/rust/src/config: no such file or directory`. Following your exact steps doesn't create anything named `config`, so that seems like your problem.

Comment: Also: you seem to be using relative paths in your code. Are you certain those relative paths are going to be correct in your container? You don't have any `WORKDIR` directives, so you working directory is `/`.

Comment: @larsks Thanks a ton. The issues was with the working directory not being set. Adding a `WORKDIR` solved it

Comment: @AdityaSingh please post an answer or close question!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem based on [*larsks* comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50670951/unable-to-read-file-inside-docker-image-using-stdfs-methods#comment88352396_50670951):

> Also: you seem to be using relative paths in your code. Are you certain those relative paths are going to be correct in your container? You don't have any `WORKDIR` directives, so you working directory is `/`.

The problem was that there was no `WORKDIR` defined and so the file read was happening from path `/`. Changing the Dockerfile like below (notice the `WORKDIR /usr/local/bin`) solved the issue:

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates

EXPOSE 3001

WORKDIR /usr/local/bin

COPY --from=builder \
    /home/rust/src/config/ \
    /usr/local/bin/config/

COPY --from=builder \
    /home/rust/src/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/app \
    /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/app

ENV RUST_BACKTRACE=1

CMD /usr/local/bin/app
```